# What's the difference between the suffix -y and the suffix -ly

Tags: grammaticality

I know how the words are used and which to use based on whether it sounds right or not, as well as that -y is used for adjectives and -ly is used for adverbs but what I'm asking is what's the meaning?

If I remember correctly -y means "with", so in the case I used it'd be "with ease". And -ly... I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Well, you couldn't do something "shakily" if it wasn't possible for something to be "shaky".

Comment: Many adverbs end in -ly, but there isn't a hard and fast rule. For instance, 'comely' and 'shapely' are both adjectives.